# Given X failures and 0 successes, how many additional Y trials to get R successes?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I believe this type of problem should be solved with negative binomial where the expected number Y is equal to r/p.

The thing I'm not sure, however, is if the distribution changes given we had X failures already. I know negative binomial distributions are not memoryless but do the initial X failures matter or affect anything in this case?

Comment: This is not clear.  Is the distribution known in advance?  That is, is the success probability, $p$, known in advance or are you trying to estimate $p$ from the history?   If $p$ is known, then the prior results have no significance.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the probability, expected value or what?